# Personally identifiable information (PII) safeguard through GDPR

Tags: gdpr

Can some one let me know how Salesforce safeguard all the Personally identifiable information (**PII**) or "**data subject**” under the GDPR rules. What are the required steps to be implement to achieve this.

Comment: There's a lot on this subject. You might want to [start here](https://www.salesforce.com/gdpr/overview/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce has different security mechanisms that safeguard data privacy that includes using Shield , Platform Encryption (Security for Data at REST), Event monitoring to track which APIs are used , Audit Trails and Field History Tracking .

All the above helps to keep the Data safe however specifically to be GDPR complaint the primary rule will be to store the consent of the user from various sources and for various channel . This [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/european-union-privacy-law-basics/units/learn-key-principles-of-the-gdpr) module talks in detail about the GDPR rules .

Salesforce offers a new object called [Individual Object](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_general_store_data_privacy_pref.htm) .This allows to store the Individual preferences and relate it back to Leads , Contacts and Person Accounts and any action or process in salesforce can take place based on the fields on this object .

Here is an excellent [article](https://medium.com/@Q9ELEMENTS/gdpr-compliance-and-salesforce-individual-object-bf41e04e7fa3) that shows an excellent strategy to be a GDPR complaint and custom object model along with salesforce objects to store consent and other data and how to leverage them in business process .